# Easy way to determine what content is not delivered using a secure HTTPS connection?

Tags: https

I have some pages that are sent via HTTPS.  Internet Explorer sometimes complains about "This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS".

I looked in the html source to confirm all content calls (href, src, etc...) are sent via https.  My CSS files use relative paths.  But I'm still getting these warnings.

Is there an easy way to track down which items are not sent via HTTPS?

Comment: Are of any of the other href, src, etc. outside of your SSL's domain?

Comment: Some of my <a href=""> links reference external websites, but they're just links.  That should be ok right?

Comment: Yep, `<a href="http://...">` is fine.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34094617/2404470) maybe useful for end users

Comment: I know this is an older post but maybe this will help someone, there's a Desktop app you can use to scan and report on mixed content issues on a site: https://www.ecommerce.co.uk/httpschecker. You can also request scan results through email too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use Firefox + [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (the "Net" tab) to find the offending request. You could also use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) for this. (with any browser)

Comment: For anyone not immediately seeing the request protocol (like poor, blind me), you can see the full URL of the request by hovering over the name of it in the FF Firebug console

Answer (score 10):

You could fire up [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what exactly IE is requesting over regular HTTP.

In Fiddler's default configuration, HTTPS requests will show up with a lock and `CONNECT` as the host.  HTTP requests will have a non-lock icon.

[image]
<sub>(source: [josh3736.net](http://josh3736.net/images/fiddlerhttps.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following site before - I finding it easier than loading up firebug / fiddler.

http://www.whynopadlock.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SslCheck](http://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/)

It's a free online tool that crawls a website recursively (following all internal links) and scans for unsecure content - images, scripts and CSS.

(disclaimer: I'm one of the developers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's an online tool, just like "whynopadlock.com" mentioned in another answer (but more powerful since its a cralwer), how can I include "essential part"?

Answer (score 2):

In [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), similar to Firefox w/ FireBug, you can use the 'Network' tab of the Developer Tools console.

Open the Developers Tools console, go to the 'Network' tab, and reload the target page. Any warnings with the page, such as insecure content being loaded, will be indicated with the number of warning and an 'alert' icon in the bottom right corner (Chrome v23.x). Click on the icon and a list of the warnings, in this case, the resources being loaded insecurely, will be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using following tools could help:

- Firefox's FireBug . opening tab Network shows you connection details to multiple resource
- Fiddler - acts as sniffer allows you explore details of connect.

Answer (score 1):

using firefox - view generated source vs viewing source

there is probably a javascript file that is creating a div/iframe that is insecure